# Zipar arquivos por linha de comando no Windows?

Tags: windows, arquivo-zip

Alguém sabe como eu zipo arquivos por linha de comando no Windows?

Obs: Não quero compactar o arquivo em sí, quero enviá-lo para uma pasta compactada.

Exemplo: Arquivo.txt --> Arquivo.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe uma ferramenta do "Windows Resources Kit Tool" chamada compress.exe . Você pode baixá-la pelo link :

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en

Depois de instalado é só usar o comando:

*C:> ”Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\compress.exe” arquivo.txt arquivo_compressado.txt*

Comment: Obrigado! Utilizei a ferramenta e foi certinho!